# to use or not to use ReleaseMouseCapture()?

Tags: c#, wpf

Using methods that work in code might be fine but not knowing exactly what is going behind the scene is not such a good feeling. Fees like a gap or incomplete job.

I happened to find `ReleaseMouseCapture()` and have used in a method (`OnMouseUp` event) since seemed necessary but I noticed using or not using this method doesn't affect the visual part of my application at least

Can you give me some idea when we should be using it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771301.aspx)

`When an object captures the mouse, all mouse related events are treated as if the object with mouse capture perform the event, even if the mouse pointer is over another object.`

Depending on exactly what you're doing it may or may not makes sense. We would need some more information. But what it boils down to is, the object that captures it will listen and receive for all events from the mouse. This way you can better organize your mouse logic. For example, Dragging an object around a screen would be perfect for this since the object itself would be getting all the mouse events.

But, if you're only using `ReleaseCaptureMouse` so not sure why you're using it. Are you using `CaptureMouse` anywhere?

Comment: I am not using CaptureMosue (in existing class) but in other ones yes. Correct me if I'm wrong, it sounds CaptureMouse and RelaseCaptureMouse are applied mostly when we are dealing with object in terms of drag and drop. Currently, I'm only dealing with drawing lines and shapes so will NOT need it. right?

Comment: Doesn't sound like you're making use of it. I don't think you need it. Of course more a lower level understanding might change my mind but from what you're saying, I don't think you need it.

Answer (score 2):

I use it whenever I write code to capture the mouse, and need to release the mouse capture when I'm finished.

A typical example would be dragging/dropping controls. When I begin a drag operation, I sometimes wish to have the application or a control capture the mouse so any movements made with the mouse are sent to the specific application or control, regardless of the mouse's actual position. When the user releases the mouse button, I need to release the mouse capture so the application/control stops receiving mouse events that its not interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to call `ReleaseMouseCapture` if you have called `CaptureMouse`, so in your case it doesn't sound like you need it.

Capturing the mouse means that the control receives mouse messages even when the mouse moves outside of the control's bounds.  It is used for things like drag & drop where the drop will occur outside of the control.